# Not able to run password masking using char[] PASSWORD =cons.readPassword in gitbash terminal

Tags: java, git-bash, masking

hi im trying to run this programme for password masking using char[] PASSWORD =cons.readPassword()
but it is giving me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at automateCFOSetup.App.main(App.java:32)
```

when i ran the programme in **git bash terminal**. But when i ran it on Windows cmd it was running fine...any reason why this occurred as i am only aware of issue of getting this null pointer when running within IDE
this is my code
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
Console cons = System.console();

```
    log.info("ENTER YOUR ID :");
    String SOEID = scan.nextLine();
    
    char[] PASSWORD =cons.readPassword("ENTER YOUR PASSWORD :");
    scan.close();
```

Any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

A console is not guaranteed to support this feature. Given that you're getting the exception, the particular console you use here (your IDE and I'm not surprised - those 'consoles' for some reason don't usually support this), **does not support password input**.

There is no solution to this. But there are workarounds:

1. You can catch the exception and tell the user: Tough luck - no can do.
2. You can catch it, and decide, eh, whatever, ask with the usual tricks (`scanner.nextLine()`). Perhaps warn the user that their pw will be echoed. Surely, 'run it in the IDE' isn't how you intend to *deploy* your software, so this isn't all that much of a security issue (if this app is used on private developer's laptops, generally those already contain so much information, such as the code itself, git keys, etc - if that device is compromised, you have much bigger problems already).
3. Don't ask on the console at all, instead, get that password from elsewhere, such as a file, using PKI. Passwords are so 1990, you know.